# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, web-scraping, output

I have used the SerpApi to web scrape from google product search. The API key has been taken out for obvious reasons. Every time I run the program, this error keeps coming up. How would I stop this from happening?

```
import json
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "api_key",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "marvel",
  "gl": "uk",
  "hl": "en",
  "tbm": "shop"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for i in range(3):
  for shopping_result in results['shopping_results']:
        try:
              title = shopping_result['title']  #Finds relating title
        except:
              title = "None"
        try:
              source = shopping_result['source']  #Finds relating title
        except:
              source = "None"
        try:
              price = shopping_result['price']  #Finds relating title
        except:
              price = "None"

        print(title)
        print(source)
        print(price)
```

[image: This is the error that I recieve]

Comment: Are you on WIndows?  Are you running this from a console, or inside an IDE?

Comment: '\u2013' is the Unicode minus sign. Having said that, I can't see anything in your code that would induce this error. Line #31 is *print(title)* which shouldn't have any trouble

Comment: I'm running this from a website called "replit"

Comment: I have an API Key for this. Your code does not induce that error. The fact that you *import json* suggests that there's more to this than the code you're showing

Comment: The code attached is everything I have, I'm not running this on a local system. I'm running it on a web server.

Comment: @HarrisonCox, please contact SerpApi support and share the search ID with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have simplified the code and removed the pointless range iteration. I have created a REPL on replit.com and this executes without error:

```
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "api_key": "<my api key>",
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "marvel",
    "gl": "uk",
    "hl": "en",
    "tbm": "shop"
}

results = GoogleSearch(params).get_dict()


for shopping_result in results.get('shopping_results', []):
    print(shopping_result.get('title', 'None'))
    print(shopping_result.get('source', 'None'))
    print(shopping_result.get('price', 'None'))
```